How can I make this code print what I need it to?
#The program awards team member prizes based on total ticket sales
#Team member total sales and prize awards are printed to the computer screen
#The program terminates when the user does not enter a 'y' or 'Y' to continue

getMoreSales = "y"
teamSales = 0

#Create a while loop to process all of the team members

while getMoreSales == "y":

#Set starting values for program variables

dayOneSales = 0
dayTwoSales = 0
dayThreeSales = 0
memberSales = 0
prizeEarned = " "

#Get sales information

print(" ")
teamMemberName = input("Enter the team member's first name ")
dayOneSales = input("Enter the day 1 ticket sales ")
dayTwoSales = input("Enter the day 2 ticket sales ")
dayThreeSales = input("Enter the day 3 ticket sales ")
memberSales = int(dayOneSales) + int(dayTwoSales) + int(dayThreeSales)
teamSales = (teamSales + memberSales)

#Determine Prize based on total tickets sold


if dayOneSales == 30>0:
print(teamMemberName, "gets a FAST STARTER! button for selling", str(memberSales), "tickets        on the first day!")

if memberSales == 41:
    prizeEarned = 'Team Sweat Shirt!'
elif memberSales == 31:
    prizeEarned = 'Team Tee Shirt!'
elif memberSales == 21:
    prizeEarned = 'Miniature volley ball!'
elif memberSales == 11:
    prizeEarned = 'Plastic mug!'
elif memberSales == 1:
    prizeEarned = 'Cup Holder!'
else:
    prizeEarned = "Team members must sell at least one ticket to get a prize"



print(teamMemberName, " sold ", str(memberSales), " tickets")
if memberSales == 0:
    print("prize awarded is: ", prizeEarned)
else:
    print(prizeEarned)

#Check if program should end

getmoreSales = input("enter y to enter more sales or n to end the program ")

#At the end of the program print total sales for the team

else:
print("The total ticket sales for the team were: ", str(teamSales))

I'm supposed to make it print that the member gets a FAST STARTER! button for selling (tickets) on the first day, when the member sells over 30 tickets on the first day.
Whenever I run my code it just says.
**Enter the team member's first name melanie
Enter the day 1 ticket sales 31
Enter the day 2 ticket sales 10
Enter the day 3 ticket sales 5
**
Enter the team member's first name
And just keeps going

getMoreSales != getmoreSales you are assigning to a different variable in your loop than you are checking for the loop condition

In your own words, what does dayOneSales == 30>0 check?

Fix the indentation of the shown code.

try change if dayOneSales == 30>0 on if dayOneSales >= 30(if inclusive 30). You is wrong type this line of code.

A few problems with your implementation:

You have a while loop and while you prompt the user to exit the loop, you never test that response and exit the loop.

All of your conditions are using == but nearly all of them should be using an inequality since you want to test things like "did the team member sell MORE THAN 30?"

For testing for the FAST STARTER! button you use variable memberSales in the text output/print. Instead you should use dayOneSales

Your indentation is broken, but that may just be copy/paste.


Here is a working version:
#The program awards team member prizes based on total ticket sales
#Team member total sales and prize awards are printed to the computer screen
#The program terminates when the user does not enter a 'y' or 'Y' to continue

getMoreSales = "y"
teamSales = 0

#Create a while loop to process all of the team members

while getMoreSales == "y":

    #Set starting values for program variables

    dayOneSales = 0
    dayTwoSales = 0
    dayThreeSales = 0
    memberSales = 0
    prizeEarned = " "

    #Get sales information

    print(" ")
    teamMemberName = input("Enter the team member's first name ")
    dayOneSales = int(input("Enter the day 1 ticket sales "))
    dayTwoSales = int(input("Enter the day 2 ticket sales "))
    dayThreeSales = int(input("Enter the day 3 ticket sales "))
    memberSales = int(dayOneSales) + int(dayTwoSales) + int(dayThreeSales)
    teamSales = (teamSales + memberSales)

    #Determine Prize based on total tickets sold


    if dayOneSales >= 30:
        print(teamMemberName, "gets a FAST STARTER! button for selling", str(dayOneSales), "tickets        on the first day!")

    if memberSales >= 41:
        prizeEarned = 'Team Sweat Shirt!'
    elif memberSales >= 31:
        prizeEarned = 'Team Tee Shirt!'
    elif memberSales >= 21:
        prizeEarned = 'Miniature volley ball!'
    elif memberSales >= 11:
        prizeEarned = 'Plastic mug!'
    elif memberSales >= 1:
        prizeEarned = 'Cup Holder!'
    else:
        prizeEarned = "Team members must sell at least one ticket to get a prize"



    print(teamMemberName, " sold ", str(memberSales), " tickets")
    if memberSales > 0:
        print("prize awarded is: ", prizeEarned)
    else:
        print(prizeEarned)

    #Check if program should end
    getmoreSales = input("enter y to enter more sales or n to end the program ")
    if getmoreSales.lower() == 'n': break    

else:
    #At the end of the program print total sales for the team
    print("The total ticket sales for the team were: ", str(teamSales))

